# Confusion about Sencha Touch 2 controllers

Tags: sencha-touch

Coming from other frameworks I'm a little bit confused about how to use controllers correctly:

I have 3 views and 3 controllers and I want each controller to run on a certain view.

```
app/
  controller/
    First.js
    Second.js
    Third.js
  model/ 
    First.js
    Second.js
    Third.js
```

`app.js` contains:

```
views: [
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third
],

controllers: [
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third
],
```

By putting all 3 controllers in `app.js` controllers field seems like all controllers are instantiated at the same time. Should I only instantiate the controller related to the Main page and initialise the next controller when the page should be changed?

Also I notice that I can include a `views` array in the controller`s`config` block. Is that meant to specify in which views should the controllers run?

Hope you can clear the confusion about how to use controllers correctly in Sencha Touch 2.

Answer (score 0):

All controllers will always be "running" always. They should run always and all should always be instantiated when your app is first loaded.

Views config on a controller allows you to specify which view classes that controller requires.

I structure my controllers to be model not view specific, as I find some controller functions are common across multiple views, but the choice is yours as to how to structure the app.